# How to install graphviz on Debian 7.7?

Tags: php, linux, installation, debian, graphviz

I'm novice in programming. I just installed my Debian and installed following packages

```
dpkg -l | grep graph
ii  graphviz                           2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        rich set of graph drawing tools
ii  libart-2.0-2:amd64                 2.3.21-2                      amd64        Library of functions for 2D graphics - runtime files
ii  libcairo2:amd64                    1.12.2-3                      amd64        The Cairo 2D vector graphics library
ii  libcdt4                            2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        rich set of graph drawing tools - cdt library
ii  libcgraph5                         2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        rich set of graph drawing tools - cgraph library
ii  libgraph4                          2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        rich set of graph drawing tools - graph library
ii  libgraphviz-dev                    2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        graphviz libs and headers against which to build applications
ii  libgvc5                            2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        rich set of graph drawing tools - gvc library
ii  libgvpr1                           2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        rich set of graph drawing tools - gvpr library
ii  libpathplan4                       2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        rich set of graph drawing tools - pathplan library
ii  libxdot4                           2.26.3-14+deb7u2              amd64        rich set of graph drawing tools - xdot library
ii  openssl                            1.0.1e-2+deb7u12              amd64        Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
```

I also used following program to start with Graphviz:

```
<?php
require_once 'Image/GraphViz.php';

$gv = new Image_GraphViz();
$gv->addEdge(array('wake up'        => 'visit bathroom'));
$gv->addEdge(array('visit bathroom' => 'make coffee'));
$gv->image();
?>
```

But What I get is:

```
addEdge(array('wake up' => 'visit bathroom')); $gv->addEdge(array('visit bathroom' => 'make coffee')); $gv->image(); ?>
```

Please let me know how to deal with this problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the PHP bindings for GraphViz. I don't have a Debian image to try this on, but try:

```
sudo apt-get install libgv-php5
```

If that doesn't work, then try:

```
sudo apt-cache search libgv | grep -i php
```

UPDATE: The code give above works against a clean Debian 7 image after the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 libgv-php5 graphviz vim php-pear
sudo pear install Image_GraphViz

# Copy the file above to test.php
php5 test.php
```

Comment: Are you sure PHP working? If you replace that file with just: `<?php echo "Hello." ?>`, do you see just `Hello.`?

Comment: Sorry, had it wrong. Image/GraphViz.php is part of a PEAR package. Try `pear install Image_GraphViz`.

Comment: Worked! Thank you